# Change update behavior of status bar

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have programmed a Excel in VBScript in such a manner that my actions are displayed bottom left hand corner of excel sheet and its working fine but the problem is that the same actions are also displayed in other Excel sheets which are opened, but unrelated to the Excel sheet on which my actions are performing.

[image: Status bar text]

How can I avoid that other Excel sheets will display the same actions?

Comment: I assume you are referring to StatusBar text. If so, this is an Application-instance control; you must open a new instance of Excel (not just another workbook) to have another StatusBar.

Comment: Attached a Link for your ref.    http://i.stack.imgur.com/GLaN3.jpg

Comment: @PieterGeerkens idea is first possibility. The other is that one who made a macro for you forgot to switch off status bar in Excel application in some situation. You could switch it manually each time you need in this way: Alt+F11 >> Immediate Window >> write there: `Application.Statusbar = false` >> press enter... if the macro is still running it is possible that the change will not be permanent depending on way the code was programmed.

Comment: The status bar is common for each workbook (entire application). Consider using another control, being only for your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the StatusBar is global and not specific to each workbook.

However, you can avoid the problem, using the `Workbook_Activate` and `Workbook_Deactivate` events. Place the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` module of your workbook:

```
Private mVarOldStatusBar As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    mVarOldStatusBar = Application.StatusBar
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If mVarOldStatusBar <> "" Then _
        Application.StatusBar = mVarOldStatusBar
End Sub
```